# Function and arrow keys not working on HP laptop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, function-keys, hp-laptop

My Laptop(1.5 yrs) is dual-booted with Windows 10(default) and Ubuntu Linux.The function keys don't work if I want to adjust the brightness or other aspects and while running BIOS the arrow keys don't work. I'd tried uninstalling/reinstalling the keyboard (PS/2) driver but in vain. I even tried the HP hardware diagnostics test for the keyboard but then they all seem to work except for the delete key(which is how that too failed).My language settings are fine and I have ensured that the filter keys have been unchecked.

Comment: Brightness is not controlled by Function keys, but by their alternative 'special function', which will be interpreted by drivers in your OS [& can be switched to use the additional Fn key to toggle which way is the default] Outside an OS with specific recognition, they will act as 'true' Function keys.

Comment: Not just this but the volume and playback settings which earlier could be operated with these keys aren't working.... infact the whole set starting from f1 to f12 has stopped functioning.

Comment: You are confusing special function with F-Keys. They are not the same thing. Special functions are controlled by drivers specific to your computer & OS; you cam probably find them on your laptop manufacturer's site. I very much doubt equivalents will be available for Ubuntu.